# Operating Systems (Synchronization)

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, pthreads

```
int i = 0;
...
void * A (void * param){
   ...
   i *= 3;
   ...
}
void * B (void * param){
   ...
   i--;
   ...
}
main(){
   pthread_t ta, tb
   ...
   pthread_create(&ta, 0, A, 0);
   pthread_create(&tb, 0, B, 0);
   ...
   printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

What can be added at "..." to ensure the output value is always maximized?

I'm guessing the solution has something to do with making sure B never executes by using a mutex, but I'm not sure

Comment: This looks like homework; please try to answer it yourself, and then ask for help. Just getting the answer handed to you on a plate will not help you grow.

Comment: I see how this looks like its homework, but this is actually from an old exam

Comment: At the first `...` in each thread: `pthread_exit(0);`, in `main()`: `i = INT_MAX;` before the `printf()`.